# Как сделать редирект без смены url?

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Есть ссылка

http://datum-s.ru/catalog/servers-and-components/rack/?SECTION_ID=servers-and-components&ELEMENT_ID=rack%2F&set_filter=y&arrFilter_163_3623318330=Y&arrFilter_298_1210362188=Y&arrFilter_266_MAX=2048&arrFilter_266_MIN=32&arrFilter_269_MAX=25&arrFilter_269_MIN=2&arrFilter_P10_MAX=3554855&arrFilter_P10_MIN=23943

Реально ли сделать для нее чпу представление, например, такое:

http://datum-s.ru/catalog/servers-and-components/rack/hp/dl160

чтобы при нажатии на вторую сслыку отрывался материал из первого, но в адресной строке была вторая?

То есть, по сути, нужен редирект, но с сохранением адреса.
Я подумал, по факту, мне нужно просто создать синоним для ссылки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Редирект тебе как раз не нужен, при редиректе меняется адресная строка. Тебе надо просто преобразование адреса.

RewriteRule Адрес_из_адресной_строки Целевой_адрес [L] # L означает, что после этого правила никакие преобразования применяться не будут.

Comment: А нет, не работает такой вариант.

Comment: А у меня работает. Какая ошибка выводится? Что вообще происходит?

Comment: Ладно, отмечу как верный, скорее всего, глюки в движке самого сайта.

Answer (score 0):

**Обновление:**

```
# arrFilter_163_3623318330=Y - фильтр указывает на servers-and-components/rack/hp
# arrFilter_298_1210362188=Y - фильтр указывает на servers-and-components/rack/hp/dl160

RewriteRule catalog/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/hp$ catalog/$1/$2/?SECTION_ID=$1&ELEMENT_ID=$2/&set_filter=y&arrFilter_163_3623318330=Y

RewriteRule catalog/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/hp/dl160$ catalog/$1/$2/?SECTION_ID=$1&ELEMENT_ID=$2/&set_filter=y&arrFilter_163_3623318330=Y&arrFilter_298_1210362188=Y
```

Comment: Рабочий, но не гибкий вариант. Лучше, конечно, ругялрки заюзать, ведь редко бывает, что нужно лишь у одной страницы применить какое-то правило.

Comment: @inferusvv, к сожалению, гибкого варианта не получится. Из URL у вас никак не выцепить производителя и модель. В любом случае придется строить карту соответствия. Пример выше...